# How to avoid repeating the namespace in Javascript

Tags: javascript, namespaces

I'm working on a backbone application.

I've structured my models + collections + views in different files.

which means a solution like 
`function() { // all my code }()`  doesn't apply here

I added a namespace e.g 
`App.ModelName App.Views.ViewName etc.`

when I'm within the same namespace. How can I avoid repeating it.
i.e how can I call ModelName when I'm in a function defined in App.Views.ViewName

at the moment I keep repeating the full string i.e App.XXXX

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have several choices:

1) Create a local variable in each function:

```
App.ModelName.myFunction = function() {
    var model = App.ModelName;
    // then you can reference just model
    model.myFunction2();
}
```

2) Create a local variable in each file scope:

```
(function() {
    var model = App.ModelName;

    model.myFunction = function() {
        // then you can reference just model
        model.myFunction2();
    }


    // other functions here

})();
```

3) Use the value of `this`:

```
App.ModelName.myFunction = function() {
    // call App.ModelName.myFunction2() if myFunction() was called normally
    this.myFunction2();   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A namespace is just an object inside the global scope.

So one alternative is to use `with` although it has some downsides.

But anyway, check out this sample:

```
window.test = {
    a: function(){ console.log(this); return 'x'; },
    b: function(){ with (this){ alert(a()); }}        // <- specifying (this)
};

window.test.b();
```

Comment: _Using `with` is not recommended, and is forbidden in ECMAScript 5 strict mode_ : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with

Comment: @AndrewD. well, I DID warn about some downsides... :P

Answer (score 1):

How about passing them as arguments? Something like this:

```
(function(aM,aV) {
    // use aM and aV internally
})(App.Models,App.Views);
```